# typescript - tsc how to copy other files type to the dist folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

Typescript compiler does not copy all files from the src folder to the dist folder.
I was not able to find any useful option for the Typescript CLI.

example:
if I have a png file along with a typescript file index.ts, running 'yarn tsc' will produce a dist folder with only the index.js file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not able to find anything included in the official doc.
I've ended up to have a "post-build" command in the package.json that runs a rsync command.

```html
{
  "build": "yarn tsc",
  "postbuild": "rsync -avum --include='*.png' --include='*/' --exclude='*' './src/' './dist'"
}
```

The following command will copy all the png files at the same location as the src.

An alternative version is

```
rsync -avu --exclude={'*.ts','*.yml','*.json','*.http','*.conf','*.sh'} "./src/" "./dist"
```

N.B.
My dist folder does not include the src folder.